# Python how to delete a directory that contains a specific word

Tags: python, directory, delete-file, shutil

Hey I want to delete folders in Windows which contain a specific string in their name.
For example I want all folders deleted with the String "Chrome"
And here existing folders:

Chrome_95.0.4638.69

Chrome_96.0.4664.45

I tried it with * but it seems like it works only if you want to delete all files with the same extensions:

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree(r'./BR/Chrome*')
```

Best Regards

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
import os
import re
import shutil
for directory in os.listdir() :
    if re.fullmatch('.*Chrome.*',directory):
        shutil.rmtree(directory)
```